# AJAX HTML function not getting textarea Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table where I am showing some data in first three columns but in last column user enters his feedback/comments. On submit, data is posted and sent via email.

**Problem is** values in textarea are not posted upon submit. I have 6 rows in my table.

**Sample TR**

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>TEST 123</td>
<td>TEST</td>
<td><input type="text" value="" id="prbt-rev" ></td>
</tr>
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
$(document).on('click','#email',function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var reportData = $("#report-data").html();

var request = $.ajax({
            url         : '<?=base_url();?>healthcheck/sendEmail',
            type        : 'POST',
            data        : {report:reportData}
        });
        request.done(function(response){
          $('#result').html(response);
        }); });
```

Comment: Where is the textarea?

Comment: you are passing html in a json object? What are you trying to feed into the data object? report can be followed by a string.

Comment: Nothing seems to correspond to the question. Unrelevant HTML markup, unrelevant js code. Improve your question to make it clearer...

Comment: i just copied areas where problem is faced

Comment: where are these fields in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `#report-data` doesn't match any element in the HTML you've shared. Either some HTML is missing or you are using the wrong selector.

The jQuery `html()` method gets the child nodes of the selected element. A text input doesn't have any child nodes. A textarea's child nodes describe its **default** value, not its current value.

Use `val()` to read the current value of a form control.

Comment: that was just an example

Comment: @jawadxiv – Examples that demonstrate the problem are better then ones that don't.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code has missing the fields that you getting in the jquery!.

Its more helpful and easy to give tips if you put here your full code here that you are using.